# Курица-тандури как пишется?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, приложение

Встретила варианты: в два слова, через дефис и даже с предлогом: курица в тандуре.  Совсем экзотический случай: тандур как имя собственное блюда: курица Тандури...

Как же ж жить?

В общем, етая курица больше рукав реглан или Москва-река?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из общих соображений: ***курица тандури***. *Или еще лучше - цыпленок, потому что так принято у кулинаров, называть молодую цельную или крупнокусочную курятину "цыпленком".* А тандури - просто печь, она же - тандыр, тонур, тонэ(ри) и тому подобное. Для дефиса нет оснований.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8

Ср.: ***цыпленок табака***. Табака - от табаки или таба (тапха), то есть грузинской сковородки особой формы. Случай полностью аналогичный.

> "курица в тандуре"

- а вот это вполне возможно, но зачем? Весь колорит пропадает.